# Does Rubocop not highlight undefined variables?

Tags: ruby, neovim, rubocop

I've installed Solargraph (which uses Rubocop) for my IDE (Neovim - using the CoC extension). Rubocop warnings are showing, but NameErrors are not detected until I run my ruby files. Is this the default behaviour, or do I need to do something more for configuration?

I'm using Ruby 2.7.2 (with rbenv).

Thanks in advance if you know the answer - I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Rubocop gives hints about coding styles. And it is highly configurable about what styles you prefer to enforce in a project. I would not expect Rubocop to discover actual syntax or naming errors and I cannot remember that Rubocop ever did. It is just not Rubocops purpose.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. I'll try to find another tool that does what I want.

Comment: Ruby autovivifies certain types of variables, and doesn't have a unique compile stage. You could possibly search for a subclass of variables that are not assigned or class names that are never instantiated, but the functionality you're looking for is intrinsically at odds with a dynamic, duck-typed, interpreted paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: `No. Because rubocop does not run your ruby code, it just parses the files.`
So, its your duty to make your code work first, then fix styles with Rubocop :)

Small hint: `you can create a github action to run both rubocop and your code on push/deploy`

Cheers!

Comment: If just parsing the files shows that a variable is used somewhere and  is define nowhere then this should be enough for a warning. Running the code will not necessarily reveal typos in variables as you may not pass into every if clause during that run. Variables don't grow out of thin air and leaving side a few super globals, they are usually scoped.

Comment: @Mecki At first I agreed with you.  `foo` within a method is always local -- right?  Well, no.  If `foo` is a variable then yes, it must be defined within the method but `foo` could be a method.  And, what is even harder to detect is the `foo` method (and probably even the `foo` local variable) could be created at run time.  Such is the penalty of interpreted languages.  Their versatility gives programmers lots of rope to hang themselves with.